# Is there a way to make a smartphone act as a beacon with react native?

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to build an app for making the smartphone to act as a real beacon. So I don’t want to check for ble beacon packets but I want my smartphone to continuously send ble beacon packets, and then they will be received from other devices. Is it possible to do that with react native? I didn’t find anything for such a purpose, the only things I found are

https://github.com/frostney/react-native-ibeacon
And
https://github.com/MacKentoch/react-native-beacons-manager

But it doesn’t seem to me that they allow to do what I want to do. I found some tutorial for doing it with native android apps, but I am interested in building a multi-platform app.

Does someone know something about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A beacon is created using either Manufacturer Data (iBeacon) or Service Data (Eddystone Beacon) as part of the advertising data.

I have not used it, but this library seems to have the functionality:

https://github.com/vitorpamplona/react-native-ble-advertiser#advertiser

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use it but whatever value I use in ```BLEAdvertiser.setCompanyId();``` it says null is not an object

Comment: Not enough information in your comment to be able to suggest anything. Suggest you start a new question with code snippet and full error messages